# multiple lookup rows in a statement

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I am looking up rows from a data extension to grab the Product (@Product) and Status (@Status) using App_number as the lookup value.
I want to then add a conditional statement in my html to the values in these rows and fields.
I have the following code. But i am not getting any results for this.
What am i doing wrong?

```
%%[
var @rows, @row, @rowCount, @numRowsToReturn, @lookupValue, @i,
set @lookupValue = AttributeValue("App_number")
set @numRowsToReturn = 0
set @rows = LookupOrderedRows("Submitted_Applications_Master",@numRowsToReturn,"Product asc, Active asc","App_number", @lookupValue)
set @rowCount = rowcount(@rows)

if @rowCount > 0 then

  for @i = 1 to @rowCount do

    var @Product, @Status, @Des
    set @row = row(@rows,@i)
    set @Status = field(@row,"Active")
    set @Product = field(@row,"Product")
      
    IF (@Product == "Electricity" AND @Product == "Broadband" AND @Status == "Pending")
    THEN 
    set @Des = "We'll let you know when we start supplying your Electricity and Broadband"
    ENDIF    ]%%
  
  <p>
    %%=v(@Des)=%%
</p>
    
   %%[ 
  next @i ]%%

%%[ else ]%%
    
       no rows found
       
%%[ endif ]%%
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a logical problem in your IF statement.

```
IF (@Product == "Electricity" AND @Product == "Broadband" (...)
```

this will never be true.

You might want:

```
IF (@Product == Electricity OR @Product == "Broadband)
AND @Status == "Pending" 
THEN
```

Comment: Sorry I should have been more clear. So there could be two records (potentially) for the same customer. 1) Electricity with a Status of "Pending' and 2) Broadband with a Status of "Active". But the code (when it worked) was only looking at the first record it seems. Maybe a lookup isn't the right starting point if i want to write a Statement using conditional data from multiple rows